# React not updating attribute on re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a React element with a name attribute and child text, both of which are taken from the same value in props.

When re-rendering a React component with a different prop value, only the child text is updated, but the name attribute stays the same:

```
var Inner = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      var name = this.props.name;
      return ( <div name={name}>{name}</div> );
    }
});

React.render(<Inner name="red"/>, document.getElementById('outer'));
// element is now <div name="red" data-reactid=".0">red</div>

React.render(<Inner name="green"/>, document.getElementById('outer'));
// element is now <div name="red" data-reactid=".0">green</div>
```

As you can see, after the second call to `React.render`, the name attribute is still red. (see http://jsfiddle.net/chyp9mxL/)

This problem can be resolved by adding a `key={name}` in the render function, but I don't see why I have to. Aren't keys only needed when we have multiple components? We only have one here.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you have two `React.render()`...

Comment: This is working fine with the new version of react and react-dom. So, include react-dom and call ReactDOM.render instead of React.render and that should do it.

Comment: @Chris Just to provide the simplest example to illustrate the problem. I imagine in real life the second render would be triggered by some user action.

Comment: @FrancoRisso you are right. I tried it with v15.3.1 and it seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Is it because `div` does not recognize `name` as a valid prop? I remember reading that passing illegal props to native DOM elements may give unexpected results.

Adding `key` as a prop simply would have given that `div` an identity. So React could identify that child and update the value properly.

> The key here is to understand not everything in the DOM has a
>   representation in React "Virtual DOM" and, because direct
>   manipulations of the DOM (like a user changing an  value or a
>   jQuery plugin listening an element) are unnoticed by React, not using
>   unique and constant keys will end up with React recreating the DOM
>   node of a component when the key is not constant (and losing any
>   untracked state in the node) or reusing a DOM node to render another
>   component when the key is not unique (and tying its state to this
>   other component).

Says [this](https://coderwall.com/p/jdybeq/the-importance-of-component-keys-in-react-js) article. But it's really strange! I hope someone comes up with a proper explanation.

Comment: Looks like so since rendering `<input>` instead correctly picks up the name attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Even if the attribute is illegal, this behaviour is inconsistent. Looks like it's a bug that has been fixed in the latest version of React.

Comment: @jmak Can you drop a link that can verify this? Would love to know!

Answer (score 0):

Because div is not a react component, you can just pass props to react components! You need read more about react prop,[here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html) is react props documents.